# Simpler computing of value

Tags: javascript

I've got a silly one here, I'm totally drawing a blank on how to solve this one easier.

So, I've got a `property` object. That has some props of its own. Now depending on the state of these props, the property is at a certain step of its lifetime. Results can go from step 1 to 3 for now, but more are coming.

Is there an easier way to find the current step than doing that:

```
const computeStep = (property) => {
  const { has_binding_offer, has_non_binding_offer } = property;
  let step;
  if (has_non_binding_offer.state === false
      && has_binding_offer.state === false) {
    step = 1;
  }
  if (has_non_binding_offer.state === true
      && has_binding_offer.state === false) {
    step = 2;
  }
  if (has_non_binding_offer.state === true
      && has_binding_offer.state === true) {
    step = 3;
  }

  return step;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: If the code is working already, you should probably ask this in codereview instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: will there be new props on `property` object, other than given two.?

Comment: It might in the future yes. That would add to the logic

Comment: It's rarely necessary to write `var === true` or `var === false`. Just use `if (var)` or `if (!var)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could encode the steps with the offer information, then use a simple filter to find the corresponding step:

```
const steps = [
  { step: 1,
    non_binding: false,
    binding: false 
  },
  { step: 2,
    non_binding: true, 
    binding: false,
  },
  { step: 3,
    non_binding: true,
    binding: true
  }
];

const computeStep  = ({ has_binding_offer, has_non_binding_offer }) => {
  const [step] = steps.filter(s => s.non_binding === has_non_binding_offer 
                                   && s.binding === has_binding_offer)
                      .map(s => s.step);

  return step;
}
```

Side question: With two values there should be 4 unique states, but I see that you are not representing the case where `has_binding_offer === true` and `has_non_binding_offer === false`. Is that just a domain thing?

Comment: thanks for your answer, that's because `has_binding_offer` can only happen after `has_non_binding_offer` is true. It's really a step by step process

Comment: @GotTheFeverMedia makes sense, I figured it was a domain specific thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used it as is (small tweak) and it worked perfectly, even when adding parameter

Answer (score 0):

Because a false value evaluates to 0 and a true one to 1 you could use:

```
step = has_non_binding_offer.state + has_binding_offer.state +1
```

But that approach breaks if you are dependent on specific propertys.

I would prefer @Hunter McMillen code.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the decision in a different way - first determine the has_non_binding_offer.state and then determine the has_binding_offer.state.

I used ternary equations to reduce content of the if statements.

```
const computeStep = (property) => {
  const { has_binding_offer, has_non_binding_offer } = property;
  let step;

  has_non_binding_offer.state
      ? (step = has_binding_offer.state ? 3 : 2)
      : (step = has_binding_offer.state ? null : 1);
  return step;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A list of booleans can be expressed as an integer using boolean arithmetic.

For example, `[true, false, true] => binary`101`==`4*1 + 2*0 + 1*1`==`5`.

A terse way to do that in Javascript is:

```
const reducer = (acc, value) => (acc << 1) | value;
const toBits = arr => arr.reduce(reducer);
```

(I originally wrote `(acc << 1) | (value ? 1 : 0)` but JS does this conversion implicitly)

Example: `[true, true, false].reduce((acc, val) => (acc << 1) | val)` evaluates to `6`.

So you can do:

```
const computeStep = ({ has_binding_offer, has_non_binding_offer }) => 
  [has_binding_offer, has_non_binding_offer]
     .map( v => v.state )
     .reduce( (acc, value) => (acc << 1) | value );
```

This returns a different integer for each possible input, and works for arrays of up to 32 booleans.

Also note: you were already doing object decomposition in your code, but I've moved it into the function parameters to save a line of code and the otherwise unused variable `property`.

To make it return the exact results you need, you might need to adjust with one of:

- Tweak the order of the input array so that the booleans are in the necessary
   positions
- Use the integer as a key to a map: `return stepMap[bits]`
- Use the integer as the input to a `switch` statement: `switch(bits) { ... }`

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I wish I could use it as it looks cleaner than the others unfortunately I couldn't make it work. Also, my linter doesn't like the bit-wise operator. Should have mentioned that before

Comment: Fix your linter ;)

Comment: Seriously, eslint warns on bitwise operations for a good reason -- it's often a typo for `||` or `&&`. But you can override with `/*eslint ...` comments. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-bitwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use a data structure to map the combinations to values:

```
var offerMap = {
    false: { false: 1 },
    true: { false: 2, true: 3 }
};
step = offerMap[has_non_binding_offer.state][has_binding_offer.state];
```

Comment: This would require a guarantee that even if `has_non_binding_offer.state` was `false`, `has_binding_offer` existed and has a `false` `state` property.  That may be true, but I see nothing from the question to ensure this.

Comment: He mentioned the dependencies in a comment, so `[false][true]` is supposed to be an impossible combination. But you could always add a dummy entry for completeness.

Comment: I was suggesting that the complete object might be `{has_non_binding_offer: state{false}}`, without any `has_binding_offer` property.  But I suppose that wouldn't match the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Does this (untested) not do the same thing?

```
const comp = (p) => p.has_non_binding_offer.state ? p.has_binding_offer.state ? 3 : 2 : 1
```

Some people object to nested conditional (ternary) operators.  But I think at time they're the clearest solution.

If you like, you can also format it like this:

```
const computeStep = (property) => property.has_non_binding_offer.state 
  ? property.has_binding_offer.state 
    ? 3 
    : 2 
  : 1
```